# BeautifulSoup - How to print attribute value?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have HTML code with multiple `<li>` lines:

```
<li class="item" data-label="Apples"> <input name="amshopby[product_groupcode_filter][]" style="" type="checkbox" value="5568"/><a class="am-filter-item-5f3d517457902" data-am-js="filter-item-default" href="https://local.internal/index.php?product_groupcode_filter=5568" rel="nofollow"><span class="label">Apples</span> <span class="count">30<span class="filter-count-label">items</span></span> </a> </li>

<li class="item" data-label="Bananas"> <input name="amshopby[product_groupcode_filter][]" style="" type="checkbox" value="5568"/><a class="am-filter-item-5f3d517457902" data-am-js="filter-item-default" href="https://local.internal/index.php?product_groupcode_filter=5569" rel="nofollow"><span class="label">Bananas</span> <span class="count">30<span class="filter-count-label">items</span></span> </a> </li>
```

I'm trying to extract just the value of the `data-label` attribute, how that could be done using BeautifulSoup ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply grab all li tags with the class items and print the data-label value.

```
litags = soup.find_all("li", class_="items")
for litag in litags:
    print(litag['data-label'])
```